# Make fewer HTTP requests

Tags: magento-1.9, http-request

I Checked my site in the gtmetrix and i got one of the following suggestion

> Make fewer HTTP requests
>
> This page has 55 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.

How can i solve this.I had google lot but still not got success.

What i have tried it Defer Javascript Parsing.ie loading the javascript after page completed loading. still no use

Comment: 55 javascript files on one page!  Definitely combine those puppies.  That's still quite the remarkable amount.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to system->configuration->Developer->JavaScript Settings and set `Merge JavaScript Files` to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try Google PageSpeed for Nginx or Apache. This can help address many other issues you'll find in YSlow and PageSpeed tests.